# Dual memory channel unavailable on DELL DIMENSION 8300

Tags: memory, dual-channel

I ran a DELL performance check on my computer (DELL DIMENSION 8300). Also I asked for a memorry configuration report. The result is a follows

Available Memory    60.92 %
Page File Size  3,071.1MB
Available Page File     98.47 %
Virtual Memory  6,138.4MB
Available Virtual Memory    79.63 %
CHANNEL A DIMM 0    1,024.0MB
CHANNEL B DIMM 0    512.0MB
CHANNEL A DIMM 1    1,024.0MB
CHANNEL B DIMM 1    512.0MB

Yet the BIOS reports System Memory Channel Mode SINGLE.

How can that be as the channel seems matched to me?

Comment: This is something can be enable or disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Not a chance. The BIOS does not allow the status to be changed. It only shows it. Not editing allowed.

Comment: What does the status show?  On my computer I am able to control that information which is the reason I worded my statement the way I did .

Comment: it shows it in BLUE. It reads STYSTEM MEMORY CHANNEL MODE SINGLE.

Comment: Try switching Channel A with Channel B.

Comment: Did you upgrade (add) memory? The manual cautions - "If you remove your original memory modules from the computer during a memory upgrade, keep them separate from any new modules that you may have, even if you purchased the new modules from Dell. You should install your original memory modules in pairs either in connectors DIMM1 and DIMM2 or connectors DIMM3 and DIMM4. If possible, do not pair an original memory module with a new memory module. Otherwise, your computer may not function at optimal performance."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dual channel enabled' will appear in BIOS, but ONLY if the proper RAM is installed.

Channel A = slot 1 & 3, and channel B = slot 2 & 4 ( different colors)

RAM within each channel has to be same size MB, same number of chips, and have similar timings.

So the best way to resolve it is to remove the 512MB sticks from DIMM B and try again. If you do see the option in BIOS just upgrade your memory. If you don't try again with the 1024MB in DIMM B.

Comment: @ TomEus I did this: Moved the 512 Mb chips to Channel 1 and took the 1Gb chips out and tested if the memory dual channel was enabled. It was. Then put the two 1Gb chips on Channel 2 and tested again. It was dual channel. Problem solved. Thanks you all guys.

Answer (score 2):

Your memory needs to be balanced across channels and with the same size in matching slots for best performance and dual channel operation.

```
CHANNEL A DIMM 0 1,024.0MB
CHANNEL B DIMM 0 1,024.0MB
CHANNEL A DIMM 1 512.0MB
CHANNEL B DIMM 1 512.0MB
```

Currently A has 2GB and B 1GB which is not balanced.